# Cordova android: Getting 404 error in angular js app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I am developing an application in android using cordova and angularjs (onsenui front end framework).
Here is my get request to fetch some data from server

```
$http.get(url+"getlotterylist").then(function(msg){
        $scope.loading=false;
        $scope.items=msg.data;
    },
    function(err){
        alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
          console.log("Error"+JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    );
```

**CASE 1**

When  running  app in browser i will get the  desired output (get request works fine).

**CASE 2**

Build my app in android platform and import to android studio.
At this point the http get request returns the following error

> {"data":"","status":404,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://example.com?action=getlotterylist","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}"

Also  enabled CORS in my php

```
<?php

  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 //api request response
?>
```

Why i am getting this error when running my app in phone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Installing  Cordova white-list plugin solves my problem

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Thank you!  I ran into the same problem and was getting quite frustrated.Adding t he white list plugin solved for me too.